# Seleccionar columnas en R con nombre variables

Tags: r, select, tidyverse

Tengo diferentes tablas en las que necesito seleccionar 2 columnas en concreto. El problema radica en que una de ellas no tiene el mismo nombre en todas las tablas, por lo que estoy obligado a cambiar ese parámetro en mi script cada vez que quiero utilizar una de las tablas. Quería saber si existe alguna forma de poner un OR para que busque todas las posibles opciones de nombre de la columnas. Os dejo abajo el código que utilizo.

```
tabla <- read.csv("tabla.txt")
tabla <- select(tabla, Run, Age)
```

La columna "Run" siempre tiene este nombre en todas las tablas. Pero la columna "Age" no; a veces se llama así, "Age", otras "Host_age", otras "age_num", otras ni siquiera aparece el "age" y tiene un nombre muy diferente... Por lo que me veo obligado a abrir la tabla, buscar la columna en cuestión y luego poner el nombre en el select(). Quería saber si donde va el "Age" puedo poner de alguna forma varias opciones.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En `tidyselect` hay un "helper" para seleccionar columnas que es útil para esto, se trata de [`one_of()`](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/one_of.html), la idea es que le pases la lista de posibles nombres de columnas, tendrías que indicar todas las posibles:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(one_of("cilindrada", "cyl", "cil")[1])
```

Cuidado que `one_of()` recupera cualquier columna coincidente, si solo quieres una, nos quedamos con la primera usando `[1]`. En tu caso podría ser algo así:

```
select(tabla, Run, one_of('Age', 'Host_age')[1])
```

Comment: Ok, gracias. Desconocía esa opción. Lo probaré. Saludos.